# Confused about Artin's Algebra 15.7.9

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

This a problem from Artin's *Algebra*, 15.7.9.(c).

> 7.9. Work this problem without appealing to Theorem (15.7.3). Let $F=\mathbb{F}_p$.
>
> (a) Determine the number of monic irreducible
> polynomials of degree 2 in $F[x]$.
>
> (b) Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible
> polynomial of degree 2 in $F[x]$. Prove that $K=F[x] /(f)$ is a field
> of order $p^2$, and that its elements have the form $a+b \alpha$,
> where $a$ and $b$ are in $F$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in $K$.
> Moreover, every such element with $b \neq 0$ is the root of an
> irreducible quadratic polynomial in $F[x]$.
>
> (c) Show that every
> polynomial of degree 2 in $F[x]$ has a root in $K$.
>
> (d) Show that all
> the fields $K$ constructed as above for a given prime $p$ are
> isomorphic.

Following the result of this problem, it seems that $f(x)=x^2-3\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-2)=\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt{2})$, but this is obviously wrong. What's wrong with this?

Comment: In general $x^2+2$ need not be irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p$. For example, if $p=3$ $x=1$ and $x=2$ are roots of $x^2+2$.

Comment: @Marcos. Yes, you are right. But if $X^2+2$ is irreducible? Like $p$=5.

Comment: In $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2)$ we have $x^2+3=x^2+3+x^2+2=2x^2$. Hence $x=0$ is a double root of $x^2+3$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2)$.

Comment: @Marcos Sorry, there are typos. The polynomials in my problem should be $x^2-2$ and $x^2-3$.

Comment: Why is it "obviously wrong"?

Comment: @EricWofsey. The "obviously wring" is my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Goldmund if the polynomials are $x^2-2$ and $x^2-3$ we are in the same situation as before. For $p=5$ we have $x^2-3=2x^2$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2-2)$ so $x=0$ is a double root of $x^2-3$. What is your problem? I mean, your ''counterexamples'' are wrong, so do you have troubles with any part of the problem? If so, tell us so we can hep you.

Comment: @Marcos. Yes, as you say, the example is wrong. I incorrectly thought that the root of $x^2-3$  is $\sqrt{3}$, and $\sqrt{3}$ does not lie in any extension field of finite field.

Comment: @Goldmund Indeed the root of $x^2-3$ is $\sqrt{3}$ (because by definition the square root of $3$ is the number whose square is $3$) However, one do not use the notation$\sqrt{3}$ outside characteristic $0$, since it may lead to confusion. For example the square roots of $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$ are $0$, so they not share the same properties about linearly independence you want to have. You have to make sure what you mean by $\sqrt{3}$ and you will be ok.

Comment: @Marcos. Thank you, your support helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are both non-squares in $F$, then $ab$ is a square in $F$, say $ab=c^2$ with $c\in F$. Now if $x$ is a square root of $a$ in $F[X]/(X^2-a)$, then $c/x$ is a square root of $b$.